# There's no question of something

Tags: ambiguity

> The banks have made it clear that there's no question of customers losing their credit status in light of the recent mortgage rate scandal.

According to the dictionary:

> there's no question of (something):
>
> 1. There is no doubt that something exists or is the case.
> 2. There is no possibility that something is the case or will happen.

So actually this sentence has 2 meanings which contradict each other, although I'm aware that the most possible reading is: customers won't lose their credit status.

My question is why this construction has 2 opposite meanings.  Could you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: The two different usages are 1) *There's no question **of** X [being true]* (X is definitely ***not true***, and that assertion cannot be questioned / refuted), and 2)  *There's no question **that** X [is true]* (X is definitely ***true***, and *that* assertion cannot be questioned). It's all about the preposition - something *has already been decided*, and that decision can't be reversed, but whether the decision is that something is true, or that something is false depends on how exactly it's phrased.

Comment: (That's to say, there are ***two*** different "constructions" here, not just one.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers How about _There's no question of his loyalty_? Can you not say this to mean that there's no doubt about his loyalty?

Comment: I didn't think of this before, but *There's no question of his loyalty / guilty / honesty* means he definitely ***is*** loyal / guilty / honest. Which is the "opposite" of *There's no question of him going to prison* (he definitely ***won't*** go to prison).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: *There's no question **that** [something will happen]*
> ...is almost always an emphatic assertion that "something" ***will*** happen.
> *There's no question that he will go to prison*  (he ***will***)

> 2a: *There's no question **of** [something happening]*
> ...almost always means that something definitely ***won't*** happen.
> *There's no question of him going to prison*  (he ***won't***)

> 2b: *There's no question **about** [something happening / being true]*
> ...(relatively uncommon) usually means it ***will*** happen / is true.
> *There's no question about him being guilty*  (he ***is***)

> 2c: *There's no question **of | about** [attribute]*
> ...usually means "attribute" is true / real / exists.
> *There's no question of his honesty*  (he ***is*** honest)
> *There's no question about his guilt*  (he ***is*** guilty)

It's important to note that since there's "no question, no doubt, no uncertainty", it's almost always contextually obvious which of the two "superficially opposite" senses applies with 2a / 2b / 2c above

---

See [The English Linguistics Project](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_English_Linguistics_Project/TzSWDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22there%27s%20no%20question%20of%20him%22&pg=PT75&printsec=frontcover) for more details.